# Lightswitch custom contol grid column not refreshing on sorting

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In my model I have two related fields: `integer` which is stored in DB and a computed `string` field which is used for grid. The text displayed is based on the int field's value.

Now the problem with computed fields is they cannot be sorted when used in a grid. My workaround is:

1. create a custom control, which contains a label
2. add it to the grid and set it's DataContext to the integer field

The label inside my UserControl uses a `IValueConverter` to display the propert text and sorting is still possible, because grid uses the `integer`.

Unfortunately when I click the header although the grid's data does get sorted, the custom controls' text doesn't refresh.

What should I do?

Comment: Eventually I switched from IValueConverters to simple choice lists as available in Lightswitch

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WCF RIA Service. When LightSwitch consumes the WCF RIA Service, it does not know the fielsd are computed fields and treats them normally.

see:
[Using WCF RIA Services In LightSwitch To Simplify Your Application UI](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/52/Using-WCF-RIA-Services-In-LightSwitch-To-Simplify-Your-Application-UI.aspx)